# jQuery: full Page horizontal slide

Tags: jquery, slide

Can anyone help me with a full page slide to the left and right.
I want to create a fixed header with the links and want to slide the bottom div to the left or right. [sample webpage](http://www.interactivegoods.com/fss/#/introduction)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this example, lets say your main content is x pixels wide.

Create a large div that is 3x pixels wide, which contains 3 inline divs x pixels wide each.

You can now simulate the sliding by adjusting the `margin-left` of the outermost div. When `margin-left` is 0, the leftmost child div will be visible. When it equals`-x`, the middle content will show, and so on.

Make sure you set `overflow:hidden` for the outer div.

This should be enough to get you started. Unless you were looking for someone to code it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at supersized, it's a jquery plugin ,
http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html

also google for jquery full page sliders, there are tons of them

ex:
http://machoarts.com/21-beautiful-jquery-sliders-for-your-next-project

Answer (score 1):

Ive used http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/ successfully for this purpose

though you need to set width to 100% in jquery.pageslide.css